# How to replace a letter in a string with another letter

Tags: ruby

I want to replace the letter `"e"` with the number `"3"`. I want `"elijah".my_method()` to return `"3lijah"`.

I tried using `sub` and `gsub` methods along with `replace`, but none of these replaces the letter. Here is my code:

```
class String
  define_method(:leet_speak) do
    containsE = self.include?("e") 

    whereIsE = self.index("e")
    whereIsE.replace("3")
  end
end
```

Comment: No, your code doesn't replace a letter, it raises an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the code you showed alters the original string (`self`) or returns an altered string. So nothing happens.

Try it like this (I have no idea why you're using `define_method` here, but I have no objection):

```
class String
  define_method(:leet_speak) do
    self.gsub("e","3")
  end
end

s = "elijah".leet_speak()

puts s # => 3lijah
```

Comment: _"I have no idea why you're using define_method here"_ – based on the code I'd say the OP doesn't know any better. But you certainly do ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The `String#tr` method lets you do multiple transformations at once.

So if you wanted to do all the leet alphabet:

`'elijah'.tr('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', '48cd3f9h1jklmn0pqr57uvwxy2')`

returns:

`3l1j4h`

Answer (score 0):

```
# The Replace Class
class Replace

   def replace_letter( string_to_replace )
      puts string_to_replace.tr('e', '3')
   end

end

# Create a new object
main = Replace.new()

# Output String after replace
main.replace_letter('elijah')
```

The **String#tr** method is enough to you...